# SSRS Report expressions on column group values

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing simple issue. The environment using is SSRS 2008. 
I have a requirement as shown below (and this is rendering using tablix).

```
                        Header1           Header2            Header3
Name          col1   col2   col3  col1  col2  col3   col1   col2   col3
Praveen         1     2       3    2     1     3      3      2       1
Kumar           3     3       1    2     3     1      3      2       1
.
.
.
reddy           4     2       2    2      1     1     1      1       1
```

Now, I have to add one more columns where I need to show the calculation/expression as shown below.

Header4 column expression:
Header2 col2 / Header3 col2

Header5 column expression
Header1 col1 / header2 col4

I tried adding a outside group column but failed to load values. All the headers are hard-coded. I can use them in expression. But, how can I get the values of a specific column group header name????? Please let me know if you don't understand the issue.

-Praveen.

Comment: In your above example, what does the underlying data look like before it's transformed into the tablix?

Comment: It should be something like `=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value/ReportItems!Textbox2.Value` . What is error you are getting. Also you can just solve this in sql instead of doing it in designer.